# How to fetch and output properly data from table, inserted with mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I used mysqli_real_escape_string() to insert the data from a html form textarea input into the MySQL table.
The input was like:

[image]

It was inserted in table properly.
But when I fetch it and try to echo it, it prints in single line as

```
  Hi H"ow" are you? I 'm f'ine /\ How you doing?
```

How to display it the way it was inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `nl2br()` to convert new lines to `<br>` then store it.

for more information : http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

for whitespaces and indentation use `html_entities()`

If it also doesnt work then you would have to do it using `str_replace()` by replacing those charcter with one in html  like `&nbsp;`

Comment: Solves the problem of new lines, but doesnt solve the problem of whitespaces and indentation

Comment: Thanks. Worked. First I had to to do str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $notice);
and then nl2br() of it.